# Ruby on Rails Selenium Cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec, cloud9-ide

I am using Cloud9 to develop a Ruby on Rails Application. In the application, I am using Rspec and Selenium. However, when I run my tests I get the following error:

```
An error occurred in an after hook
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to obtain stable firefox connection in   60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) occurred at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@rails4/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:79:in `connect_until_stable'
```

I have tried installing firefox and xvfb but these applications were up to date.

How can I run the tests in Cloud9?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to your use of Rspec but I know Cloud9 has a good integration with Sauce Labs that allows for extensive browser testing with Selenium. You can use this if you:

1. Preview your desired file or page
2. Click "Browser" or the word shown in the dropdown in the top right side of the preview
3. Click "Desktop Browser" or "Mobile Browser"
4. Select the browser you want to test

Comment: This does not work for whatever reason. I tried this originally and it did not work.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about which part does not work? Do you get an error message at some point or does it just hang?

Answer (score 0):

I too couldn't get Selenium working in Cloud9. When I tried launching a Selenium webdriver - either by running tests or in IRB with `Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox` - I got the 'unable to obtain stable Firefox connection' error. What finally worked was installing Firefox xvfb (rather than just Firefox) and running tests with xvfb-run:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox xvfb
```

Then

```
xvfb-run rake
```

I don't really understand why this works but Selenium wouldn't launch with Firefox normally. If anyone can explain that would be great!